# Difference between if and whether

Tags: if, whether-if

I know that 'if' and 'whether' are sometimes interchangeable but what is the main reason that 'if' can't be used in following sentence?

> ________ philosophy should be taught at school has become a matter of controversy for students and teachers alike.

Comment: Who said that it can't? Did you read that somewhere? Where? [Where did you find the example sentence?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)

Comment: "Whether" definitely sounds better, but that doesn't mean "if" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

'If' and 'whether' can generally both be used to indicate a response to an indirect question with a binary choice. However, the grammar around them can be different - you can't always just switch one word for the other.

For example:

- *I don't know whether **or not** I am going* ✔
- <s>*I don't know if **or not** I am going*</s> ✘
- *I don't know if I am going **or not*** ✔

The issue with your example is that both 'if' and 'wether' can also be used to introduce *conditions*.

For example:

- *If you go, I will go.*
- *I will go whether you go or not*.

As you can see, the grammatical structure is also different for both.

Beginning a sentence with 'if' sounds like you are introducing a condition, and that is why it would not be an idiomatic choice for your example.